# NavigationControllerのNavigationBarのタイトルに画像を設定する方法

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, navigationbar

NavigationControllerのNavigationBarのタイトルに画像を設定しようとしていますがうまくいきません。
ネットで探してみた所下記方法で大丈夫という説明をみたのですが試してみた所画像が表示されません。

```
UIImageView *titleImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleImageView;
```

普段NavigationBarは自分でストーリボードから作成していますが、TableViewのスタティックセルはUITableViewControllerでなければ使えないためNavigationControllerのNavigationBarを使おうとしています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

どうぞ。

Objective-C

```
    UIImageView *titleView = [UIImageView new];
    titleView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
    titleView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navi_icon"];
    titleView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    self.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
```

Swift

```
    let titleView = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30))
    titleView.image = UIImage(named: "navi_icon")
    titleView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    self.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
```

Comment: 残念ながら本方法ではうまくいきませんでした。

Comment: 上手くいくように少しだけ編集しておきました。
それでもわからなければGitHubにサンプルを置いておいたので、DownloadZIPボタンからダウンロードして確認して下さい。

https://github.com/masuhara/NavigationBarTitleImageSampler

Comment: うまくいきました。ありがとうございます。